# Stored procedure for adding a new row to a table, which checks the values to validate their values on foreign tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have created a basic database for a wine enthusiast collection.I am trying to write the core stored procedure which is to add a wine to the Wine table.

Given that many of the values in the Wine table have foreign key constraints, I need to write a procedure which accomplishes these tasks:

/*  Check whether the type and/or grape are in their respective tables already. If not add it to Type and/or Grape */

/*  Most people when entering the storage location, won't know the locationID, they will know the rack number and cellID. So it needs to check the rack number and cellID and return the LocationID assoc. with it. Also, update the boolean StorageLocation.Empty to be false for that location. */

/*  Most people won't know the vintnerID they will just know the vintnerName. So if it exists in the Vintner table return the ID assoc. with it, if not add it to Vintner and return the ID assigned to it */

/*  Most people wont know the OriginID, they will have the Country, and maybe region. So it would need to check if it exists in the Origin table and return the ID assoc. with it, and if not add it to Origin and return the ID assigned to it*/

These are the main goals I have with this question. Any insight and advice is greatly appreciated to anyone willing to spend the time to assist me! This is my first database, so I'm sure there are glaring structural problems, I'm just hoping if you can explain the logic needed and how to go about it I can figure it out. Thank you again!

Copy and paste all below this point:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS wino;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wino CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE wino;

CREATE TABLE Member
(
    MemberID        INT             UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT       PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName       varchar(25)     NOT NULL,
    LastName        varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Address         varchar(50)     NULL,
    City            varchar(50)     NULL,
    StateID         varchar(2)      NULL,
    Zip             varchar(15)     NOT NULL,
    Phone           varchar(15)     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MEMBER
    (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, StateID, Zip, Phone)
VALUES('Guy', 'Faux', '1542 5th St', 'Monte Cristo', NULL, '8204931', '2-424-515-2412');

CREATE TABLE StorageLocation
(
    LocationID      INT             AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    LocationName    varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    RackNumber      varchar(5)      NOT NULL,
    CellID          varchar(5)      NOT NULL,
    Empty           Boolean         DEFAULT     TRUE
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rackNumberCellID
    ON StorageLocation (RackNumber, CellID);
ALTER TABLE StorageLocation
    ADD CONSTRAINT uq_LocationID UNIQUE(LocationName, RackNumber, cellID);

INSERT INTO StorageLocation
    (LocationName, RackNumber, cellID)
VALUES
    ('Main','1', 'A1'),
    ('Main','1', 'A2'),
    ('Main','1', 'A3'),
    ('Main','1', 'A4'),
    ('Main','1', 'A5'),
    ('Main','1', 'B1'),
    ('Main','1', 'B2'),
    ('Main','1', 'B3'),
    ('Main','1', 'B4'),
    ('Main','1', 'B5'),
    ('Main','1', 'C1'),
    ('Main','1', 'C2'),
    ('Main','1', 'C3'),
    ('Main','1', 'C4'),
    ('Main','1', 'C5'),
    ('Main','1', 'D1'),
    ('Main','1', 'D2'),
    ('Main','1', 'D3'),
    ('Main','1', 'D4'),
    ('Main','1', 'D5'),
    ('Main','1', 'E1'),
    ('Main','1', 'E2'),
    ('Main','1', 'E3'),
    ('Main','1', 'E4'),
    ('Main','1', 'E5'),
    ('Main','1', 'F1'),
    ('Main','1', 'F2'),
    ('Main','1', 'F3'),
    ('Main','1', 'F4'),
    ('Main','1', 'F5'),
    ('Main','2', 'A1'),
    ('Main','2', 'A2'),
    ('Main','2', 'A3'),
    ('Main','2', 'A4'),
    ('Main','2', 'A5'),
    ('Main','2', 'A6'),
    ('Main','2', 'A7'),
    ('Main','2', 'A8'),
    ('Main','2', 'A9'),
    ('Main','2', 'B1'),
    ('Main','2', 'B2'),
    ('Main','2', 'B3'),
    ('Main','2', 'B4'),
    ('Main','2', 'B5'),
    ('Main','2', 'B6'),
    ('Main','2', 'B7'),
    ('Main','2', 'B8'),
    ('Main','2', 'B9'),
    ('Main','2', 'C1'),
    ('Main','2', 'C2'),
    ('Main','2', 'C3'),
    ('Main','2', 'C4'),
    ('Main','2', 'C5'),
    ('Main','2', 'C6'),
    ('Main','2', 'C7'),
    ('Main','2', 'C8'),
    ('Main','2', 'C9'),
    ('Main','2', 'D1'),
    ('Main','2', 'D2'),
    ('Main','2', 'D3'),
    ('Main','2', 'D4'),
    ('Main','2', 'D5'),
    ('Main','2', 'D6'),
    ('Main','2', 'D7'),
    ('Main','2', 'D8'),
    ('Main','2', 'D9'),
    ('Main','2', 'E1'),
    ('Main','2', 'E2'),
    ('Main','2', 'E3'),
    ('Main','2', 'E4'),
    ('Main','2', 'E5'),
    ('Main','2', 'E6'),
    ('Main','2', 'E7'),
    ('Main','2', 'E8'),
    ('Main','2', 'E9'),
    ('Main','2', 'F1'),
    ('Main','2', 'F2'),
    ('Main','2', 'F3'),
    ('Main','2', 'F4'),
    ('Main','2', 'F5'),
    ('Main','2', 'F6'),
    ('Main','2', 'F7'),
    ('Main','2', 'F8'),
    ('Main','2', 'F9'),
    ('Main','2', 'G1'),
    ('Main','2', 'G2'),
    ('Main','2', 'G3'),
    ('Main','2', 'G4'),
    ('Main','2', 'G5'),
    ('Main','2', 'G6'),
    ('Main','2', 'G7'),
    ('Main','2', 'G8'),
    ('Main','2', 'G9'),
    ('Main','2', 'H1'),
    ('Main','2', 'H2'),
    ('Main','2', 'H3'),
    ('Main','2', 'H4'),
    ('Main','2', 'H5'),
    ('Main','2', 'H6'),
    ('Main','2', 'H7'),
    ('Main','2', 'H8'),
    ('Main','2', 'H9'),
    ('Main','2', 'I1'),
    ('Main','2', 'I2'),
    ('Main','2', 'I3'),
    ('Main','2', 'I4'),
    ('Main','2', 'I5'),
    ('Main','2', 'I6'),
    ('Main','2', 'I7'),
    ('Main','2', 'I8'),
    ('Main','2', 'I9'),
    ('Main','2', 'J1'),
    ('Main','2', 'J2'),
    ('Main','2', 'J3'),
    ('Main','2', 'J4'),
    ('Main','2', 'J5'),
    ('Main','2', 'J6'),
    ('Main','2', 'J7'),
    ('Main','2', 'J8'),
    ('Main','2', 'J9'),
    ('Main','3', 'A1'),
    ('Main','3', 'A2'),
    ('Main','3', 'A3'),
    ('Main','3', 'A4'),
    ('Main','3', 'A5'),
    ('Main','3', 'A6'),
    ('Main','3', 'A7'),
    ('Main','3', 'A8'),
    ('Main','3', 'A9'),
    ('Main','3', 'B1'),
    ('Main','3', 'B2'),
    ('Main','3', 'B3'),
    ('Main','3', 'B4'),
    ('Main','3', 'B5'),
    ('Main','3', 'B6'),
    ('Main','3', 'B7'),
    ('Main','3', 'B8'),
    ('Main','3', 'B9'),
    ('Main','3', 'C1'),
    ('Main','3', 'C2'),
    ('Main','3', 'C3'),
    ('Main','3', 'C4'),
    ('Main','3', 'C5'),
    ('Main','3', 'C6'),
    ('Main','3', 'C7'),
    ('Main','3', 'C8'),
    ('Main','3', 'C9'),
    ('Main','3', 'D1'),
    ('Main','3', 'D2'),
    ('Main','3', 'D3'),
    ('Main','3', 'D4'),
    ('Main','3', 'D5'),
    ('Main','3', 'D6'),
    ('Main','3', 'D7'),
    ('Main','3', 'D8'),
    ('Main','3', 'D9'),
    ('Main','3', 'E1'),
    ('Main','3', 'E2'),
    ('Main','3', 'E3'),
    ('Main','3', 'E4'),
    ('Main','3', 'E5'),
    ('Main','3', 'E6'),
    ('Main','3', 'E7'),
    ('Main','3', 'E8'),
    ('Main','3', 'E9'),
    ('Main','3', 'F1'),
    ('Main','3', 'F2'),
    ('Main','3', 'F3'),
    ('Main','3', 'F4'),
    ('Main','3', 'F5'),
    ('Main','3', 'F6'),
    ('Main','3', 'F7'),
    ('Main','3', 'F8'),
    ('Main','3', 'F9'),
    ('Main','3', 'G1'),
    ('Main','3', 'G2'),
    ('Main','3', 'G3'),
    ('Main','3', 'G4'),
    ('Main','3', 'G5'),
    ('Main','3', 'G6'),
    ('Main','3', 'G7'),
    ('Main','3', 'G8'),
    ('Main','3', 'G9'),
    ('Main','3', 'H1'),
    ('Main','3', 'H2'),
    ('Main','3', 'H3'),
    ('Main','3', 'H4'),
    ('Main','3', 'H5'),
    ('Main','3', 'H6'),
    ('Main','3', 'H7'),
    ('Main','3', 'H8'),
    ('Main','3', 'H9'),
    ('Main','3', 'I1'),
    ('Main','3', 'I2'),
    ('Main','3', 'I3'),
    ('Main','3', 'I4'),
    ('Main','3', 'I5'),
    ('Main','3', 'I6'),
    ('Main','3', 'I7'),
    ('Main','3', 'I8'),
    ('Main','3', 'I9'),
    ('Main','3', 'J1'),
    ('Main','3', 'J2'),
    ('Main','3', 'J3'),
    ('Main','3', 'J4'),
    ('Main','3', 'J5'),
    ('Main','3', 'J6'),
    ('Main','3', 'J7'),
    ('Main','3', 'J8'),
    ('Main','3', 'J9'),
    ('Main','4', 'A1'),
    ('Main','4', 'A2'),
    ('Main','4', 'A3'),
    ('Main','4', 'A4'),
    ('Main','4', 'A5'),
    ('Main','4', 'A6'),
    ('Main','4', 'A7'),
    ('Main','4', 'A8'),
    ('Main','4', 'A9'),
    ('Main','4', 'B1'),
    ('Main','4', 'B2'),
    ('Main','4', 'B3'),
    ('Main','4', 'B4'),
    ('Main','4', 'B5'),
    ('Main','4', 'B6'),
    ('Main','4', 'B7'),
    ('Main','4', 'B8'),
    ('Main','4', 'B9'),
    ('Main','4', 'C1'),
    ('Main','4', 'C2'),
    ('Main','4', 'C3'),
    ('Main','4', 'C4'),
    ('Main','4', 'C5'),
    ('Main','4', 'C6'),
    ('Main','4', 'C7'),
    ('Main','4', 'C8'),
    ('Main','4', 'C9'),
    ('Main','4', 'D1'),
    ('Main','4', 'D2'),
    ('Main','4', 'D3'),
    ('Main','4', 'D4'),
    ('Main','4', 'D5'),
    ('Main','4', 'D6'),
    ('Main','4', 'D7'),
    ('Main','4', 'D8'),
    ('Main','4', 'D9'),
    ('Main','4', 'E1'),
    ('Main','4', 'E2'),
    ('Main','4', 'E3'),
    ('Main','4', 'E4'),
    ('Main','4', 'E5'),
    ('Main','4', 'E6'),
    ('Main','4', 'E7'),
    ('Main','4', 'E8'),
    ('Main','4', 'E9'),
    ('Main','4', 'F1'),
    ('Main','4', 'F2'),
    ('Main','4', 'F3'),
    ('Main','4', 'F4'),
    ('Main','4', 'F5'),
    ('Main','4', 'F6'),
    ('Main','4', 'F7'),
    ('Main','4', 'F8'),
    ('Main','4', 'F9'),
    ('Main','4', 'G1'),
    ('Main','4', 'G2'),
    ('Main','4', 'G3'),
    ('Main','4', 'G4'),
    ('Main','4', 'G5'),
    ('Main','4', 'G6'),
    ('Main','4', 'G7'),
    ('Main','4', 'G8'),
    ('Main','4', 'G9'),
    ('Main','4', 'H1'),
    ('Main','4', 'H2'),
    ('Main','4', 'H3'),
    ('Main','4', 'H4'),
    ('Main','4', 'H5'),
    ('Main','4', 'H6'),
    ('Main','4', 'H7'),
    ('Main','4', 'H8'),
    ('Main','4', 'H9');



CREATE TABLE Origin
(
    OriginID                INT             UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT       PRIMARY KEY,
    Country                 varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    StateProvince           varchar(30)     NULL,
    Region                  varchar(50)     NULL,
    Vineyard                varchar(50)     NULL
);
ALTER TABLE Origin
    ADD CONSTRAINT uq_OriginID UNIQUE (Country, StateProvince, Region, Vineyard);

INSERT INTO Origin
    (Country, StateProvince, Region, Vineyard)
VALUES
    ('United States', 'CA', 'Santa Rita Hills', 'Fiddlestix'),
    ('Spain', 'Northern Spain', 'Rioja', 'Campo Viejo'),
    ('United States', 'CA', 'Adelaida', 'Tablas Creek'),
    ('United States', 'CA', 'Napa Valley Carneros', 'M2 Carneros'),
    ('United States','CA', 'Napa Valley', NULL),
    ('United States','CA', 'Lodi Mokelumne River', 'Maley-Wegat'),
    ('Italy', 'Tuscany',NULL, NULL),
    ('Italy', 'Tuscany','Cortona', NULL),
    ('Spain', NULL,'Burgos', NULL),
    ('Italy', NULL, 'Montalcino', NULL);

CREATE TABLE Vintner
(
    VintnerID       INT             UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT       PRIMARY KEY,
    VintnerName     varchar(50)     UNIQUE      NOT NULL,
    YearEstablished YEAR    NULL
);

INSERT INTO Vintner
    (VintnerName, YearEstablished)
VALUES
    ('Fess Parker', 2016),
    ('Campo Viejo', 1964),
    ('Tablas Creek', NULL),
    ('M2', 2006),
    ('Lindeman', NULL),
    ('Renwood', NULL),
    ('Emilio Lustau', NULL),
    ('Robert Biale', NULL),
    ('Carpineto',NULL),
    ('Santa Christina', 1946),
    ('Ribera del Duero', NULL), 
    ('Caparzo', NULL);

CREATE TABLE WineType
(
    TypeName        varchar(40)     UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO WineType
    (TypeName)
VALUES
    ('Pinot Noir'),
    ('Red Blend'),
    ('Vermentino'),
    ('Cream Sherry'),
    ('Chardonnay'),
    ('Port'),
    ('Rose'),
    ('Chenin Blanc'),
    ('White Blend'),
    ('Savignon Blanc'),
    ('Pecorino'),
    ('Prosecco'),
    ('Voigner'),
    ('Syrah'),
    ('Shiraz'),
    ('Petite Syrah'),
    ('Zinfandel'),
    ('Toscano'),
    ('Tempranillo'),
    ('Sangiovese');

CREATE TABLE Grape
(
    GrapeName       varchar(40)     UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Grape
    (GrapeName)
VALUES
    ('Pinot Noir'),
    ('Tempranillo'),
    ('Vermentino'),
    ('Chardonnay'),
    ('Syrah'),
    ('Savignon Blanc'),
    ('Zinfandel'),
    ('Cabernet Sauvignon'),
    ('Voigner'),
    ('Grenache'),
    ('Sangiovese');

CREATE TABLE FoodType
(
    FoodType        varchar(40)     UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO FoodType
    (FoodType)
VALUES
    ('Fish'),
    ('Beef'),
    ('Pork'),
    ('Chicken'),
    ('Duck'),
    ('Lamb'),
    ('Italian'),
    ('Indian'),
    ('Asian'),
    ('Cheese');


CREATE TABLE Food
(
    FoodName        varchar(40)     UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY
);


CREATE TABLE Wine
(
    WineID          INT             UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT       PRIMARY KEY,
    MemberID        INT             NOT NULL,
    WineName        varchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    TypeName        varchar(40)     NOT NULL,
    GrapeName       varchar(40)     NULL,
    VintnerID       INT             NOT NULL,
    OriginID        INT             NOT NULL,
    LocationID      INT             NOT NULL,
    Vintage         YEAR            NULL,
    Rating          varchar(10)     NULL,
    BottleSize      varchar(15)     NULL    DEFAULT '750ml',
    ABV             FLOAT           NULL,
    Price           FLOAT           NULL,
    PurchasedFrom   varchar(30)     NULL,
    DatePurchased   DATE            NULL,
    DrinkByDate     DATE            NULL,
    TastingNotes    varchar(500)    NULL,
    Pairing         varchar(40)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_typeName foreign key (TypeName)
        REFERENCES WineType (typeName)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_grapeName foreign key (GrapeName)
        REFERENCES Grape (grapeName)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_vintnerID foreign key (VintnerID)
        REFERENCES Vintner (vintnerID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_originID foreign key (OriginID)
        REFERENCES Origin (originID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_locationID foreign key (LocationID)
        REFERENCES StorageLocation (LocationID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Pairing foreign key (Pairing)
        REFERENCES FoodType (foodType)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_MemberID foreign key (MemberID)
        REFERENCES Member (memberID)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO Wine
    (WineName, TypeName, GrapeName, VintnerID, OriginID, LocationID,
    Vintage, Rating, BottleSize, ABV, Price, PurchasedFrom, DatePurchased, 
    DrinkByDate, TastingNotes)
VALUES
    ('Fess Parker Pinot Noir', 'Pinot Noir', 'Pinot Noir', 1, 1, 214,
    2016, NULL, DEFAULT, 14.3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Campo Viejo Rioja', 'Red Blend', 'Tempranillo', 2, 2, 142,
    2013, NULL, DEFAULT, 13.5, 13, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Aroma of wild cherries, pepper, and oak' ),
    ('Tablas Creek Vermentino', 'Vermentino', 'Vermentino', 3, 3, 119,
    2016, NULL, DEFAULT, 12.9, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    'The 2016 Vermentino has a classic 
    Vermentino nose of grapefruit pith, citrus leaf, 
    fresh herbs and sea spray, but with an extra level 
    of creaminess beyond what we usually see, like key lime pie. 
    The palate is zingy with flavors of lemon, nectarine, 
    and a briny mineral note that comes out on the long, clean, bright finish. 
    Drink now and over the next few years.'),
    ('M2 Pinot Noir los carneros','Pinot Noir', 'Pinot Noir', 4, 4, 182, 
    2015, NULL, DEFAULT, 13.8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Black Chicken', 'Zinfandel', 'Zinfandel', 8, 5, 126,
    2015, NULL, DEFAULT, 14.8, 31, 'Vineria', '2018-05-01', NULL, NULL),
    ('M2 Zinfandel', 'Zinfandel', 'Zinfandel', 4, 6, 183,
    2015, NULL, DEFAULT, 14.6, 25, 'M2 Wines', NULL, '2020-05-01', 'Peppery'),
    ('Dogajolo', 'Toscano', 'Sangiovese', 9, 7, 269,
    2015, NULL, DEFAULT, 13, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    'Fruity, intense, berries, coffee, vanilla and spice'),
    ('Santa Cristina Toscano', 'Toscano', 'Sangiovese', 10,8, 123,
    2016, NULL, DEFAULT, 13, 15, 'Binnys', '2018-06-01', '2020-01-01', 
    'Ripe berry fruit, floral notes'),
    ('Valderiz', 'Tempranillo', 'Tempranillo', 11, 9, 245,
    2014, NULL, DEFAULT, 15, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('Brunello di Montalcino', 'Sangiovese', 'Sangiovese', 12, 10, 261,
    2012, NULL, DEFAULT, 14, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


/* Is there an easier way to update StorageLocation.Empty for every entry in Wine?  */

UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 214;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 142;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 119;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 182;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 126;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 183;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 269;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 123;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 245;
UPDATE StorageLocation
SET Empty = FALSE
WHERE LocationID = 261;
```

Comment: Please edit your post, drag select highlight all code and press the {} button above the text box to format your code

Answer (score 0):

Though long, your post only contains one question:

> /* Is there an easier way to update StorageLocation.Empty for every entry in Wine? */

Yes, don't specify a where clause:

```
UPDATE StorageLocation SET Empty = FALSE;
```

The other stuff is something stackoverflow isn't necessarauly designed to help with; we don't tell you how to architect or implement entire application features, we help you get over problems you encounter along the way. That said, the instructions you have are pretty specific and lend themselves to informing you on a particular pattern of programming. I'll give some guidance on how to implement the required features in a generic sense but a large part of the design and implementation choices are yours alone to make. Try to keep in mind that no one is here to do your homework for you and you should always make an attempt at writing some code and then post it up for us to see - not only does it show willing but it helps us understand how you think, which can be critical to getting to grips with where you're struggling

As an acadenic exercise you're being asked to write a stored procedure that takes human relatable values in and looks them up to turn them into the ID values the database uses when maintaining its relationships

> Most people won't know the vintnerID they will just know the vintnerName. So if it exists in the Vintner table return the ID assoc. with it, if not add it to Vintner and return the ID assigned to it

Implies your stored procedure might look like:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE blah (
  blah parameters, 
  vintnerName VARCHAR,
  more blah parameters
)
AS
BEGIN

  blah code

  DECLARE vintID INT;
  SELECT ID INTO vintID FROM vintners WHERE name = vintnerName;

  IF vintID IS NULL THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unknown vintner name';
  END IF;

  blahblah code...

END;
```